# Creating all possible combinations in a vector from 0 to 5 with step 1?

Tags: for-loop

I have this MATLAB code and it begins on vector `U = [0 0 0]` and going to end at `U = [5 5 5]`. My goal is to find all possible vectors between `U = [0 0 0]` and `U = [5 5 5]` with the step `1`.

Sure, this one is easy.

```
U = [0 0 0];
step = 1;
max_value = 5;
min_value = 0;


for j = min_value:step:max_value
  for k = min_value:step:max_value
    for l = min_value:step:max_value
      sprintf("%f,%f,%f", j, k, l)
    end
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,0.000000,5.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,1.000000,5.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,2.000000,5.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,3.000000,5.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,4.000000,5.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,0.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,1.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,2.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,3.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,4.000000
ans = 0.000000,5.000000,5.000000
ans = 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000
ans = 1.000000,0.000000,1.000000
ans = 1.000000,0.000000,2.000000
ans = 1.000000,0.000000,3.000000
....
....
....
ans = 5.000000,5.000000,5.000000
```

But assume that we have vecor `U` with `n` elements. Then multiple for-loops cannot be used. Instead I need to use somthing like this:

```
  for i = 1:length(U)
    for j = min_value:step:max_value
      U(i) = j;
    end
  end
```

But that does not work neither. Do you have any suggestions how to create this loop for an arbitary vector `U`?

It does not matter what language you are using. I just tried out it with MATLAB, but C works good too.

Comment: What do you mean by an _arbitary vector_?

Comment: @SardarUsama An arbitary vector is something between $N$ and $M$, but still suitable. For example. An arbitary value can be like 1, 2, 100, 500, 40, 5, but not infinity or very very large.

Comment: `Us= [0 0 0];   step = [1 1 1];   Ue = [5 5 5];`
`A = arrayfun(@(a,b,c) colon(a,b,c), Us,step,Ue,'un',0);`
`U = fliplr(combvec(A{:}).');`  Something like this?

Comment: @SardarUsama These are arbitary vectors yes.

Comment: Okay so? ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry, I don't understand you?

Comment: I was not asking if you had those vectors or not. Have you tried running that? Does it give you the expected solution?

Comment: @SardarUsama See my answer below. Now it's working.

Comment: That's irrelevant to your actual post. It was not originally a  C language question. Also you don't seem to have tried what I suggested

Comment: @SardarUsama You probably should write an answer instead about what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute-force solution can be this:

```
N = 3;
min_value = 0;
max_value = 5;
step = 1;
U = min_value.*ones(1, N);

idx = length(U); % index of the element to be changed
while (1)
    if (U(idx) <= max_value-step)
        U(idx) = U(idx) + step; % increase the element
        U % display
    elseif (sum(U) == N*max_value)
        break; % all elements are maxed, get out
    else
        % current index is maxed, so move left
        idx = find(U <= max_value - step, 1, 'last'); % get the rightmost element that is not maxed
        U(idx) = U(idx) + step; % increase it
        U(idx+1:end) = min_value; % reset all elements to the right of it
        idx = length(U); % restart from the rightmost element
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution i C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void increment(uint8_t* index, float* u, uint8_t* elements, float* step, float* max_value, float* min_value){
    if(*index >= *elements - 1)
        return;
    *index = *index + 1;
    u[*index] += *step;
    if(u[*index] > *max_value){
        u[*index] = *min_value;
        increment(index, u, elements, step, max_value, min_value);
    }
    *index = *index - 1;
}

void print_vector(float* A, int row, int column) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%0.18f\t", *(A++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    // Initial parameters
    float u[3] = {0,0,0};
    uint8_t elements = 3;
    float min_value = 0;
    float max_value = 20;
    float step = 1;

    // Start clock
    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    // Do the process
    uint8_t index = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < powf(max_value - min_value + 1, elements); i++){
        for(float j = min_value; j <= max_value; j += step){
            u[index] = j;
            print_vector(u, 1, elements);
        }
        increment(&index, u, &elements, &step, &max_value, &min_value);
    }

    // Compute the speed
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```